# Ensure File Extension Matches File Type in C++

Tags: c++, string

all.  I am trying to write a C++ program that will iterate through a user-specified directory (e.g. /home/alpernick/Pictures).  Primarily, this is to ensure that there are no duplicates (checked via md5sum).

But one feature I truly want to include is to ensure that the extension of a filename matches the file's type.

For example, if the file's name is "sunrise.png" I want to ensure that it actually is indeed a PNG and not a mislabeled JPEG (for example).

I am approaching this with four functions, as follows.

- string extension(string fileName) // returns the extension of fileName (including .tar.gz handling, so it isn't blindly just returning the last 3 characters)
- string fileType(string fileName) // This one is the key -- it returns the actual file type, so if the file named fileName is a PNG, fileType() will return PNG, regardless of the return value of extension()
- string basename(string fileName) // Rerturns the basename of the file, I.e. everything before the extension (so, for sunset.jpg, it would return sunset; for fluffytarball,tar.gz, it would return fluffytarball)
- string renameFile(string incorrectFileName, string fileNameBeforeExtension, string actualFileType) // Returns a string whose value is the basename concatenated with the correct file extension.

```
string file = sunset.jpg;
/* Setting file to be hard-coded for illustrative purposes only */
if(extension(file) != fileType(file)
{
    char fixedName [] = renameFile(file, basename(file), fileType(file));
    puts(fixedName);
}
```

I have zero issues with the string processing.  I'm stuck, however, on fileType().  I want this program to not only run on my primary machine (Kubuntu 14.04), but also to be capable of being run on a Windows machine as well.  So, it seems I need some library or set of libraries that would be common to both (or at the least compiled for both).

Any help/advice?

Comment: You'll need to know the file formats of what you want to check, and know where to expect certain indicators for the type from the content (e.g. magic numbers for certain file types). I doubt, there are such available for arbitrary types of files.

Answer (score 2):

There are more exceptions than rules for guessing the actual type of a file based on its contents.

This is exacerbated by the fact that a file can be valid and useful interpreted as two completely different file types.

For a good program trying to guess on insufficient data, try `file` on Unixoids.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at `file` source code: https://github.com/file/file .

But as wikipedia states

> file's position-sensitive tests are normally implemented by matching various locations within the file against a textual database of magic numbers (see the Usage section). This differs from other simpler methods such as file extensions and schemes like MIME.
>
> In most implementations, the file command uses a database to drive the probing of the lead bytes. That database is implemented in a file called magic, whose location is usually in /etc/magic, /usr/share/file/magic or a similar location.

So it does not seem trivial.

Comment: I was accidentally vague (despite the specifics):  I am only interested in PNG, JPG, GIF - the program's purpose is to check for duplicates in a directory of image files (non-image-type files (text files, archives, etc, would be skippped), so what I am looking for is for image files only, to ensure a file whose extension is .png is, in fact, a png file.

I am trying to do this in C++, as I had stated above, and in the title.  So I need some form of library for C++, not a shell utility like 'file'.